# Javascript creation of unique copy of given string text

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

var  list = ["Text", "Text - Copy", "Text - Copy(1)", "Text - Copy - Copy", "Text - Copy(1) - Copy"];

I am trying to create such unique list. These all are actually copy of String "Text". I am stuck with logic of creating unique suffixes. Suffixes will only be either " - Copy" or " - Copy(n)"; n being the number of copy(n= {1, 2, 3,....}). Second part is something like we do while creating new folder in windows (Only difference is in windows if we create another new folder it is named as new folder(2) and so on but here is " - Copy(1)", " - Copy(2)" and so on). This naming convention is part of my original requirement.

**Concept:**
Consider empty string array
User provides some input, logic should create copy of that input as in the picture embedded in the link:
Please visit this link and check download sample.jpg:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=16853795955702626977

Basically, if my array is empty and input is lets say "Text" then logic should provide me output and final array output as in 1st entry. If not then consider 2nd entry, here i provide same input once more, ideally output should be "Text - Copy" but since it is already there in final array, output should be "Text - Copy(1)". Logic should be able to deduce this once it has processed the output and is going to add in final array.

If same input ("Text") is supplied third time then output string should be "Text - Copy(2)". There can be input as in 3rd or 4th entry also. Input will always be from "set" of final array itself i.e. if my final array is ["Text", "Text - Copy", "Text - Copy(1)", "Text - Copy - Copy", "Text - Copy - Copy(1)"] then the choice of input is one these values.

This way it should be able to create unique array. Logic should be implementable with both empty array or the array given in very beginning.

Now, what i am doing is that using regex (JavaScript match method) i am finding count of "Copy" in the input. if count is 0 then input is as like 1st or 2nd entry and then i am searching that whether the generated output is in final array or not, based on this search i am either suffixing " - Copy" or just adding/updating n in " - Copy(n)". If there are very few entries then this logic works out fine but with more entries everything goes for a toss.

Please help!!

Thanks

Comment: I think the way its done in Windows explorer is to take the current clip file, add ` Copy` to name, if it exists, add additional `space (n)`, if it exists, increment the `(n++)` until it finds a slot.

Comment: Worked perfectly...it was like very few LOC!!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this fiddle out.

http://jsfiddle.net/sggndr6x/3/

The main part is like following

(you need underscore.js)
    function do_it(input, final_arr){

```
    var SUF =  ' - Copy'

    // input text is first occurence in final_arr
    if(!_(final_arr).contains(input)){
        return input
    }

    // input text is the second occurence in final_arr
    var copied = input + SUF
    if(!_(final_arr).contains(copied)){
        return copied
    }

    var reg = new RegExp(copied + '\\((\\d)\\)$')
    var matches = _(_(final_arr).map(function(d){ return d.match(reg) })).compact()

    // final_arr == ['text', 'text - Copy']
    if(matches.length == 0){
        return copied + '(1)'
    }

    // final_arr == ['text', 'text - Copy', 'text - Copy(1)', .. 'text - Copy(n)' ]
    var max = _.max(matches, function(m){ return parseInt(m[1]) })
    return max[0].replace(/\(\d+\)$/, '(' + (parseInt(max[1]) + 1) + ')')
}
```

Comment: Quite complex but it'll do